# Changing Clustering Coefficient in Cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape, cytoscape-web

If I change any parameter like clustering coefficient, average shortest path length, it is not showing any effect on the visualization of the network.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.  If you want the network to reflect a parameter like that, you need to use an edge-weighted layout and then select that column as the weight.  Note that if you manually change the value, you will need to relayout the network.

-- scooter